# Is there a word or phrase that means: similar in scenario, but opposite in cause/reason?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, a friend and I are playing a game and we are both stuck at a certain point in said game.

I'm stuck because my character isn't strong enough, I don't do enough damage. My friend is stuck because their character isn't tough enough, they cannot take any hits.

Both of these are similar scenarios, we can't get past this part of the game, but the reason we each can't is completely opposite.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, RareRush, can you include an example sentence, that will show how you plan to use this word or phrase in a construction. For example, if I was looking for a word to describe 'feeling happy' my example sentence might look like: *I am ........... today* - this is a requirement of asking questions where you are seeking answers that suggest a word or words you can use, as it makes your intended usage perfectly clear.

Comment: @Gary - Ideally the example sentence should be one that can only really take the word the OP is looking for.  It should help to provide context and nuance of meaning.  For example it might help us to decide whether to suggest *ecstatic* or *euphoric* or *blissful* or *tickled pink*...

Comment: @Jim - Yes the example was deliberately trivial to outline the basic concept, contextual specifics will of course relate to the op's intended usage. But good point.

Comment: What would be wrong with *for different reasons* or *from different causes* or some such?